How to handle new fields in a STRUCT when dynamically adding using union on all tables in BigQuery
Process
In BigQuery, Google Analytics data is linked to a BigQuery project. Each site corresponds with a dataset, and each day an events_* table is added to that dataset. My query dynamically iterates over all datasets and tables, performs a UNION of them all updating when new event_* tables are added, daily, to a destination table.
Issue
One of the fields in the events_* tables changed a few days ago. The field: collected_traffic_source had 4 new columns added to its STRUCT. Older events_* tables don't have the extra fields which causes this error
Query error: Query column 27 has type STRUCT<manual_campaign_id STRING, manual_campaign_name STRING, manual_source STRING, ...> which cannot be inserted into column collected_traffic_source, which has type STRUCT<manual_campaign_id STRING, manual_campaign_name STRING, manual_source STRING, ...> at [3:3]

I recreated the unioned table with the additional columns, but get the following error due to older tables not having them when I rerun the query.
Query error: Inserted row has wrong column count; Has 28, expected 32 at [3:3]

Question
Is it possible to update the query so it handles based on the number of columns for the collected_traffic_source STRUCT and INSERT based on that?
Query
DECLARE dataset_name STRING;
DECLARE dataset_counter INT64;

-- Get list of datasets matching the pattern 'analytics_xxx'
CREATE TEMP TABLE datasets AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() rownumber, schema_name AS dataset_name
  FROM google-analytics-prod.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA
  WHERE schema_name LIKE 'analytics_%'
);

SET dataset_counter = 1;
-- Iterate through datasets
WHILE dataset_counter <= (SELECT MAX(rownumber) FROM datasets)  DO
  -- Fetch the next dataset name
  SET dataset_name = (SELECT dataset_name FROM datasets WHERE rownumber = dataset_counter);
  --Error occurs here
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT('''
  INSERT INTO bi.production.google_analytics_brandsites
  SELECT "%s" AS dataset_brandsite, _TABLE_SUFFIX AS events_tbl_name, PARSE_DATE('%%Y%%m%%d', t.event_date) event_date_formatted,t.event_date, t.event_timestamp, t.event_name, t.event_params, t.event_previous_timestamp, t.event_value_in_usd, t.event_bundle_sequence_id, t.event_server_timestamp_offset, t.user_id, t.user_pseudo_id, t.privacy_info, t.user_properties, t.user_first_touch_timestamp, t.user_ltv, t.device, t.geo, t.app_info, t.traffic_source, t.stream_id, t.platform, t.event_dimensions, t.ecommerce, t.items, t.collected_traffic_source, t.is_active_user FROM google-analytics-prod.%s.events_* AS t
  WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM bi.production.google_analytics_brandsites  AS d
    WHERE t._TABLE_SUFFIX = d.events_tbl_name
    AND
    "%s" = d.dataset_brandsite
  )
  ''', dataset_name, dataset_name, dataset_name)
  ;
  SET dataset_counter = (dataset_counter + 1);
END WHILE;


Can you unnest the STRUCT? If you do, that would be workable to fill in the missing columns with NULLs using UNNEST, so you can UNION the data as those with and those without the extra fields in the STRUCT.

@mrjuttenberg. Ended up coming up with a different solution, but I'm curious about your approach. Is it possible to use IF EXISTS for a field within a CASE to determine the STRUCT that don't have the field paths. If you can, that would be a cleaner approach.

Using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN_FIELD_PATHS, allowed handling of the STRUCT dynamically, utilizing conditionals. This changed the query from dynamically iterating over just the datasets and tables within a project, to also dynamically iterating over each table and its field paths. Finally, determining the number of columns in a field path for the STRUCT and directing to a conditional.
DECLARE dataset_name STRING;
DECLARE dataset_counter INT64;
DECLARE table_name_ STRING;
DECLARE table_counter INT64;
DECLARE collected_traffic_source_exists INT64;

-- Get list of datasets matching the pattern 'analytics_xxx'
CREATE TEMP TABLE datasets AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() rownumber, schema_name AS dataset_name
  FROM google-analytics-prod.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA
  WHERE schema_name LIKE 'analytics_%'
);

SET dataset_counter = 1;
-- Iterate through datasets
WHILE dataset_counter <= (SELECT MAX(rownumber) FROM datasets)  DO
  -- Fetch the next dataset name
  SET dataset_name = (SELECT dataset_name FROM datasets WHERE rownumber = dataset_counter);
  -- Dynamically iterate through a datasets tables
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""
  CREATE TEMP TABLE tables_brandsite_31 AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() rownumber, table_name
  FROM `google-analytics-prod.%s`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  WHERE table_name LIKE 'events_%%'
  AND
  table_schema = '%s')
  """, dataset_name, dataset_name)
  ;
  SET table_counter = 1;
  WHILE table_counter <= (SELECT MAX(rownumber) from tables_brandsite_31) DO
    SET table_name_ = (SELECT table_name FROM tables_brandsite_31 WHERE rownumber = table_counter);
    --Determine number of fields within a STRUCT
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT('''
    CREATE TEMP TABLE tables_brandsite_31_fields AS (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT field_path) fieldpath FROM `google-analytics-prod.%s`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN_FIELD_PATHS
    WHERE table_schema = "%s"
    and
    column_name = 'collected_traffic_source'
    AND
    table_name = "%s")
    ''', dataset_name, dataset_name, table_name_)
    ;
    SET collected_traffic_source_exists = (SELECT fieldpath from tables_brandsite_31_fields
      )
    ;
    -- Conditional for if the expected fields exist
    IF collected_traffic_source_exists = 13 THEN

      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT('''
      INSERT INTO `analytics.production.google_analytics`
      SELECT "%s" AS dataset_brandsite, "%s" AS events_tbl_name, PARSE_DATE('%%Y%%m%%d', t.event_date) event_date_formatted,t.event_date, t.event_timestamp, t.event_name, t.event_params, t.event_previous_timestamp, t.event_value_in_usd, t.event_bundle_sequence_id, t.event_server_timestamp_offset, t.user_id, t.user_pseudo_id, t.privacy_info, t.user_properties, t.user_first_touch_timestamp, t.user_ltv, t.device, t.geo, t.app_info, t.traffic_source, t.stream_id, t.platform, t.event_dimensions, t.ecommerce, t.items, t.collected_traffic_source, t.is_active_user, t.is_active_user, t.batch_event_index, t.batch_page_id, t.batch_ordering_id FROM `google-analytics-prod.%s.%s` AS t
      WHERE NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM `analytics.production.google_analytics`  AS d
        WHERE d.events_tbl_name = "%s"
        AND
        "%s" = d.dataset_brandsite
      )
      ''', dataset_name, table_name_, dataset_name, table_name_,table_name_,dataset_name)
     ;ELSE
      --handle the older tables without the field paths of structs by filling with NULL
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT('''
      INSERT INTO `analytics.production.google_analytics`
      SELECT "%s" AS dataset_brandsite, "%s" AS events_tbl_name, PARSE_DATE('%%Y%%m%%d', t.event_date) event_date_formatted,t.event_date, t.event_timestamp, t.event_name, t.event_params, t.event_previous_timestamp, t.event_value_in_usd, t.event_bundle_sequence_id, t.event_server_timestamp_offset, t.user_id, t.user_pseudo_id, t.privacy_info, t.user_properties, t.user_first_touch_timestamp, t.user_ltv, t.device, t.geo, t.app_info, t.traffic_source, t.stream_id, t.platform, t.event_dimensions, t.ecommerce, t.items,
      STRUCT(t.collected_traffic_source.manual_campaign_id,
      t.collected_traffic_source.manual_campaign_name,
      t.collected_traffic_source.manual_source,
      t.collected_traffic_source.manual_content,
      NULL AS manual_source_platform,
      NULL AS manual_creative_format,
      NULL AS manual_marketing_tactic,
      t.collected_traffic_source.gclid,
      t.collected_traffic_source.dclid,
      t.collected_traffic_source.srsltid) AS collected_traffic_source,
      t.is_active_user,
       
      
      FROM `google-analytics-prod.%s.%s` AS t
      WHERE NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM `analytics.production.google_analytics`  AS d
        WHERE d.events_tbl_name = "%s"
        AND
        d.dataset_brandsite = "%s"
      )
      ''', dataset_name, table_name_, dataset_name, table_name_, table_name_,dataset_name)
            
  ;
  END IF;
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tables_brandsite_31;
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tables_brandsite_31_fields;
  SET table_counter = (table_counter +1);
  END WHILE;
  SET dataset_counter = (dataset_counter + 1);
END WHILE;

